# Variável perde o valor dentro do "for"

Tags: python, variáveis, for

```
a=2
for a in range (9) :
    print (a+1)
```

Por que usando o `for`, nesse caso, é impresso do 1 ao 9, sendo que a variável `a` é igual a 2?

Comment: A tradução dessa linha seria algo como _para cada "a" na faixa até 9 faça:_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, a variável `a` dentro do laço não vale 2. Embora a sintaxe não seja tão explícita, o laço usado está criando uma atribuição, então a cada passo executado o valor de `a` muda, incluindo a primeira vez. O `range()` vai gerando os valores que serão atribuídos à variável `a`, que é exatamente o que essa forma de `for` se propõe fazer. A variável ali é para ser atribuída.

Pense nele assim:

```
for a = range(9):
```

Sendo que a cada passagem virá o um novo elemento da faixa pretendida.

Se queria manter o valor de `a` então a variável do laço deveria ser outra. Se queria que a faixa começasse em 2 então deveria fazer:

```
for a in range(2, 9):
    print (a + 1)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sB6a7v). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RangeStartpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/RangeStart.py).